What are the correct scopes in Azure to both retrieve user profile picture and use IMAPS?
I am authenticating a user using OAuth 2.0 with the following scopes:
https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send offline_access openid profile

To retrieve the user profile picture I need to call this API endpoint with the access token:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

Unfortunately, this API endpoint only works if I include https://graph.microsoft.com/.default in my scopes. More unfortunately, doing so gives me the following error when logging in:
The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access openid profile is not valid. .default scope can't be combined with resource-specific scopes.

I cant seem to retrieve the profile with any scope other than the .default scope, but with that scope I cannot use IMAPS and SMTPS, which I need. What is the correct way to be able to do both?

You want get the access token with multi-scope? if your question is this, It is not possible to include scopes for different resources in the same Azure AD access token.

@wenbo I see. Is there a preferred way to get a user's profile picture without the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value endpoint? Or perhaps a outlook.office endpoint (which I presume would qualify as the same resource as the IMAP and SMTP scope)?

Hi Eshy, feel sorry, no idea of outlook.office endpoint

@wenbo I see. No worries!

@Eshy check this API https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value

@NaveenSharma I understand, of course. But, I have just come home from work and need to test the solution first. It was posted past midnight in my time zone.


Note that: I agree with @wenbo, generating access token with two resources or different resource scopes is not supported.

For sample, I generated the access token using same scope as you:
https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send offline_access openid profile


When I decoded the access token, the aud will be the scope you are passing first:
Hence here the aud is https://outlook.office.com

When you call Microsoft Graph API  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$valueusing the above token you will get error.
Hence, to resolve the error check the below:

Either generate two access token one for outlook and one for Microsoft Graph API and then call the required APIs.
Or as a workaround, use the below query:

Grant User.Read Office 365 Exchange Online API permission:

Use the below query to fetch the user profile photo:
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value

Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send https://outlook.office.com/User.Read


Microsoft suggests using Microsoft Graph API as Outlook rest API will be decommissioned, I have just given it as a workaround. Refer this MsDoc

Hi, thank you for you response. Unfortunately, the call to the https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value API results in {"error":{"code":"ConsumerPhotoIsNotSupported","message":"The photo wasn't found."}}. Also, unfortunately, Microsoft does not seem to support using IMAPS/SMTPS with the Graph API. Their documentation on it still uses the Outlook API. This is odd, however, as Azure does have Graph API equivalents for IMAPS and SMTPS in the tenant dashboard. To be clear, I have indeed testing the Graph API version of IMAPS/SMTPS and it indeed does not work.

Yeah Graph api do not work with outlook

Do you mean I cannot use IMAPS with the Graph API, or do you mean (as you said in the post) that I cannot combine the Graph and Outlook scopes?

You cannot combine both Graph and Outlook scopes

@Eshy Generating two separate tokens is not feasible for your environment?

I apologize for the delayed response. It seems we may be in strictly opposite time zones. Unfortunately, generating two separate tokens isn't ideal in my use case. Google, Yahoo, Rediff, Outlook (exchange, 365, hotmail), etc. are all supported and the same logic is used for all of them to process OAuth and IMAPS/SMTPS. Supporting two tokens would require significant change.

@Eshy By default it's not possible to achieve your requirement

And there is no way around except generating two seperate tokens

I see. For now I have just defaulted to a Outlook logo instead. Thank you so much for your help! I hope that a solution does become available soon, though.
